# Using parameter names from variable in json object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

Trying to work out a map reduce on mongo that would use field value as parameter name of the emitted object.

To simply what I'm tying to do is the following:

```
emit_object = {}
param_name = "param1"
param_value = 1
emit_object.param_name = param_value
```

The object I wish to construct is:

```
{ "param1" : 12 }
```

Yet the being constructed is the following:

```
{ "param_name" : 12 }
```

Does JS support this "dynamic" behavior of object construction? (Mongo uses SeaMonkey JS engine, if that's relevant).

Thank you,
Maxim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
emit_object[param_name] = param_value
```

Answer (score 3):

```
emit_object[param_name]
```

The name is "bracket notation", there is also "dot notation to access" Object in javascript